# How to align elements in a Dialog box?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create a Dialog box that should appear as follows:

[image]

I'm using the following axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSetDateTime" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSetDateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunately, this is appearing on the screen as

[image]

What do I need to do to get this to appear as in the drawing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use FrameLayout, just use LinearLayout looks work for you as following:

> ```
>     <DatePicker
>             android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
>             android:calendarViewShown="false" />
>
>     <TimePicker
>             android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:orientation="horizontal">
>         <Button
>                 android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
>                 android:layout_width="100dip"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Cancel" />
>         <Button
>                 android:id="@+id/btnSetDateTime"
>                 android:layout_width="100dip"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Set"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your DatePicker has some confused layout properties.  First you set it be be top of the whole view with 'alignParentTop' then you center it horizontally (fine so far,) but then you tell it to centreInParent which seems contrary to what you are trying to do.
Also from the looks of your sketch both the date and time pickers should have a width of match_parent (possibly with identical margin parameters and if you want the buttons below to fill the views width between them I would put them in a horizontal orientation linearlayout.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent vertical, LinearLayout then a child horizontal LinearLayout for your buttons.